# pad/truncate strings

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Today i went for my first interview for .Net Developer.
Interviewer asked me one tricky question but I can't able to answer that.
I thought lots on that question but not get any solution on that question.

Question is...

```
ID | Name
 1 | Ram
 2 | Prathamesh
 3 | Naresh
 4 | Dasharath
```

Update this table with following condition;
If Name's character is less than 6 letters then New value must be like "Ram***"
(* mark will be added until characters length is 6) 
and if it more than 6 letters all extra letters should be remove.

Result like this :

```
ID | Name
 1 | Ram***            /* added three * marks */
 2 | Pratha            /* removed extra letters */ 
 3 | Naresh            /* No changes */
 4 | Dashar            /* removed extra letters */
```

Comment: I could totally get this job!!

Comment: glad to here you could totally get this job...
But I think for "fresher level" it's OK for me...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT LEFT(NAME+'******',6) FROM TABLE
```

Comment: @NileshDalvi Just for reference generic approach`DECLARE @pad INT = 6; SELECT LEFT(NAME + REPLICATE('*', @pad), @pad)`

Comment: @lad2025 - It should be noted that your "generic approach" is a horrible idea, this will be quite slow running a replicate call on each row.  Unless you only have just a few (less than 10000) records.

Comment: @Hogan I think you're exaggerating. Calling replicate should not be that taxing. It's also possible the Replicate call will be optimized away since the parameters are constant inside the select, but the result of replicate should still be moved into a variable before the select.

Comment: @EliAlgranti - yes variable, I can get behind that.  I think (at least I've found) it is rare to have a requirement where the generic solution is useful.  Mostly this is to make "columns" line up with spaces or have numbers pre-fixed with zeros.  In both those cases you don't want/need the size to be dynamic.